# What does dot DB means in mongostat.exe?

Tags: mongodb, database

In a mongostat.exe I'm constantly receiving such a weird output, what can it be?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot is for global write lock.

What it means is that in that specific point of time, the global lock was held more time than any specific data base lock in respect to the previous measurement. Between those two the global db lock was held for 5% of the time

Comment: But if i'm not mistaken, mongoDB has per database lock, what does "global lock" mean in this context?

Comment: True, every db has a lock, but a [global lock exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-granular-are-locks-in-mongodb)